# How to draw a graph in Texmaker

Tags: tikz-pgf

i want to draw a graph identical to that in the photo below but unfortunately i failed, can any one please draw such a graph for me ? 
[image]

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I suggest reading the pgfplots manual. Try `texdoc pgfplots` from the command line, or just search for pgfplots examples on TeX.SX!

Comment: If you failed, you must have tried something. Can you show us the code of that attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to help you get going.  Look at the `pgfplots` manual to fill in the details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=x,ylabel=y]
\addplot[smooth] {{-x^2}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]